# Someone who gets an advantage by sucking up someone else

Tags: word-request

What do you call a student who always sucks up to the teachers / professors in order to gain better marks or an employee who get a promotion by complementing a higher manager or boss etc. in the polite and impolite way?

Comment: You could call them a creep if you wished to be impolite. How do so tactfully is not within the scope of ELL.You could try asking on [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [**Sycophant**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sycophant) *A person who acts obsequiously towards someone important in order to gain advantage.* Synonyms: *toady, creep, crawler, fawner, flatterer, flunkey, truckler, groveller, doormat, lickspittle, kowtower, obsequious person, minion, hanger-on, leech, puppet, spaniel, Uriah Heep,...*

Comment: Someone who always goes along with a boss and praises their decisions and conclusions can be called a "yes man". For some reason there does not seem to be a common equivalent gender-neutral term.

Comment: @FumbleFingers for me the closest adjective to "sycophant" in this sense would be "flatterer". Do you confirm it?

Comment: No, I don't. I can just about imagine a woman saying *You're a flatterer!* to some creepy guy who's trying to get into her pants by overdoing the compliments, but I can't see a bunch of guys standing round the office water cooler saying *John's a flatterer!* when talking about the office brownnose / creep. Bear in mind that *however* you refer to such a person, it will be a ***negative*** label, which means you're probably okay to use "slang" terms. If you're in a formal context you probably shouldn't even be talking about such matters, so you don't really need a "formal" term.

Comment: Good job. Great answer. So @FumbleFingers based on what I understood, sycophant does not work here as a formal one, because such  behaviours would be considered a bit weird in the US and when people try to look good (morally) in order to achieve something, it won't sound good at tall in AE (because there is a negative intention behind it).

Comment: So Flatterer, toady, sycophant etc. would not work and then instead the slangs like: "Suck-up" or "Brownnoser" or even "boot-licker" are some more preferred concepts in AE, though they are not polite, but based on people's beliefs, this action is as is explained by these words. So do you confirm now? :)

Comment: @A-friend: I don't really see what you mean. Are you saying that you think sycophancy *isn't* seen as a negative thing in some other countries, and that somehow this affects your choice of which word to use? I haven't actually voted on this question, but I think it's probably Primarily Opinion-based anyway (as implied by the fact that Max answered with two more terms that weren't in my original "synonyms" comment). Note that it wouldn't be "polite" to call someone *any* of these terms. Also, I'd say a sycophant is still a sycophant regardless of what people believe, or what they call him.

Comment: ...note that the ***adjective*** forms would be, for example, *a **sycophantic** attitude, a **flattering** remark*. But *a **creepy** comment* wouldn't normally be understood to mean the same thing (it would probably be interpreted as a ***disturbing / frightening*** comment).

Comment: I see the ELL sidebar keeps suggesting [Looking for a word to describe someone who always 'agrees' to their bosses](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57773/looking-for-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-always-agrees-to-their-bosses?rq=1) as a duplicate of this question, and I'm inclined to agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call the person a *suck-up*, or a *brownnoser*. These two are insults.

> - [suck-up](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suck%E2%80%93up)
>     a person who tries to get the approval of someone in authority by saying and doing helpful and friendly things that are not sincere
> - [brownnose](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brown%20noser)
>     : to try to get the approval of (an important or powerful person) by praise, flattery, etc.

Comment: Dang! *Neither* of your two suggestions are in the list I posted in my comment! All this really goes to show is there are a *lot* of different terms in this general area.

Comment: Thank you, Max. Just please let me know if "to suck up" can be used in polite cases in AE or I have to look for another alternative?

Comment: No, it's not polite. But it's not a polite concept to begin with. What I mean is that using a formal or informal word for this doesn't matter. I believe it will always be rude or impolite since it's an insult. Such behaviors are frowned upon, at least in American culture.